# VBA module sub save debug type match 13

Tags: excel, vba

I'm following a code online on how to create a data entry form, and when I click save it says

> Run-time error '13' Type mismatch

Which highlighted `iSerial = database.Cells(iRow - 1, 1).Value + 1`.

I can't seem to find the problem and I am new to the VBA thing. Here is the code

```vb
Sub Save()
    Dim frm As Worksheet
    Dim database As Worksheet
    
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iSerial As Long
    
    Set frm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employee Form")
    Set database = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employee Information")
    
    If Trim(frm.Range("N1").Value) = "" Then
        iRow = database.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        iSerial = database.Cells(iRow - 1, 1).Value + 1
    Else
        iRow = frm.Range("M1").Value
        iSerial = frm.Range("N1").Value
    End If
    
    With database
        .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = iSerial
        .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = frm.Range("H8").Value
        .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = frm.Range("H10").Value
        .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = frm.Range("H12").Value
        .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = frm.Range("H14").Value
        .Cells(iRow, 6).Value = frm.Range("H16").Value
        .Cells(iRow, 7).Value = frm.Range("H18").Value
        .Cells(iRow, 8).Value = [Text(now(), "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS")]
    End With
    
    frm.Range("M1").Value = ""
    frm.Range("N1").Value = ""
End Sub
```

If you need to see the whole code to help me :D pls dont close thise, I need grades ;-;

Comment: That means the value in that cell is not numeric.

Comment: it seems `iRow` starts from 0 and gets immediately -1

Comment: @user3598756 - I don't think so: `iRow = database.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`. There's no way that can produce anything less than 2.

Comment: I have played with it and I realized that when in the other sheet if there are no other serials present it cannot place another. how do I fix this?

Comment: As I add a row with information, it starts to work but without then it just doesnt work. ;-;

Comment: @BigBen, yes, missed that

Comment: Use `IsNumeric` to check the value before attempting to add 1.

Comment: @BigBen where do I add that?

Comment: `If IsNumeric(database.Cells(iRow - 1, 1).Value) Then`...`End If`?